# Getting email spam blacklist lists

Tags: email, blacklist, blacklist-prevention

Hi for protecting my organisation i want to get a full list of email spam blacklists from various lists. mxtoolbox for instance is able to check an ip against many many blacklists, however is it free to download the list from every blacklist?

Not only is using the blacklist important but we have thousands and thousands of IPs owned by us and our customers, i simply cannot find a solution free or paid that that allows checking that many, and instead of choking the internet with API requests i figured it would be a lot more efficient and better to download the lists not only for email filters but to also code to autonomously check against it regularly so that any IP address of ours that appear in it can be caught early for measures to be taken.

So far our email servers regularly get targetted for phishing, scams and as a relay to send spam and our customers also run their own, so it is important to be able to identify compromised servers or customers acting badly as recently we ended up on l3-UCEPROTECT list for the entire range of many thousands of IPs. However we do not get any abuse emails in relation to any of our IPs used for spam, because even though we ignore copyright emails (we arent an endpoint ISP or hosting platform) we do act on abuse emails.

While some blacklist providers make it easy to download their list, there are about 100 blacklists used commonly out there and i would like to know if all of them can provide their lists freely to test against. This is because l3-UCEPROTECT only happens if some IPs are blacklisted on other lists for a while.

Comment: Why do you want to download the lists? The common approach is to query various blacklists via DNS queries, which are cached locally. Why do you want the hassle to have to download the lists at regular intervals and manage them locally?

Comment: because of the amount of checking that has to be done. We're not dealing with domains, we do routing, and we own IPs. That means that 1 IP could have many many domains on it, depending on what the customer does. Instead of thousands of queries, running code to compare the IPs against the list is more efficient. The list doesnt contain domains but rather IP addresses.
Should the blacklist contain domains, its more efficient to resolve it since we have a direct link to google (hence their search and DNS too) without affecting the internet and other servers with huge expensive queries.